# How can I include variables as predictors but not variables to be imputed in multiple imputation with Amelia?

Tags: missing-data, multiple-imputation, mice

I am using Amelia for multiple imputation, and have a very large list of variables to predict missingness in my exposure and outcome. However, I don't want to impute values in these predictors, I only want to use them to predict missingness in the exposure and outcome.

I saw there is an option to include "idvars", but these variables will be dropped from the analysis, so won't be used as predictors. In the mice package, it is possible to edit the predictor matrix and method info to specify variables to be used only as predictors (see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62714196/imputation-with-mice-exclude-variable-from-being-imputed-but-still-use-as-pred)). Is there any equivalent option in Amelia?

Comment: Am I right to assume that the other variable are adjustment variables?  How can you use the other variables to predict the main variables without also imputing their missing values?  I could see removing observations if certain assumptions are met and all variables are missing on the same observations.

Comment: Thanks Frank for your response. The other variables aren't adjustment variables, only auxiliary variables to predict missingness. I don't think it will be possible to do it via removing observations, as the auxiliary variables aren't missing on the same observations.

Comment: So since they are missing on different observations, multiply imputing them will allow them to be used optimally for imputing the variables you care most about.

Comment: @Frank Harrell That's useful to know, thanks. I was worried imputing for all variables would make it very slow, but Amelia seems to be really fast compared to mice and it was fine.

Comment: Also try the R `Hmisc` package `aregImpute` function which may be much faster.  You may have to play with the number of knots in the cubic spline functions used to relax the linearity assumptions (MICE and Amelia assume linearity which is not reasonable in a lot of cases).